# Sonar 3D Mapping

Tags: gpio, sensor, wiring

My friend sent me this link http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aYwPX47_460sv.mp4 it's interesting I had to give him that, I want to make something similar like that but to the Raspberry Pi. Problem is I don't know where to start. My questions would be first off, **Is the Raspberry Pi powerful enough of mapping an entire room?** Secondly would be **is there a sample code already out there for sonar mapping?** It's not a really serious project it's something to fool around with, if there is no sample code, what can I do to make the map. Lastly thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the Raspberry Pi powerful enough of mapping an entire room?

This may depend on the hardware and software you want to use, but I do not see why it should not be able to do this.  Presuming the sonar unit does the appropriate low level work, the pi just has to do the mapping.

> is there a sample code already out there for sonar mapping?

This is not a pi specific question, and you would be better off exploring this on our much larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).  I suppose it might be specific to the sonar device, but hopefully there are generic forms of such that could be used with any sonar device.